# Expo error: Cannot read property 'statusBarHeight' of null

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

How to fix this error in Expo **v34.0.0**?

[image: Expo error Cannot read property statusBarHeight of null]

Answer (score 3):

In Expo, you can no longer import directly from 'expo', so change from (the old way):

```
import { Constants } from 'expo'; // OLD WAY
```

to (the updated way):

```
import Constants from 'expo-constants'; // NEW WAY
```

Similarly, if you are using the following features, use this format:

```
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';

import * as Location from 'expo-location';

import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';

import { DeviceMotion } from 'expo-sensors';
```

[Expo documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v35.0.0/sdk/constants/) is quite helpful.

If you are using the online Expo editor, you will be prompted to install the packages, so just click OK. Otherwise, run:

```
expo install expo-constants
```

Answer (score 1):

Expo separated a lot of their previously joined libraries and `Constants` is one of them, to get the constants now, follow along:

1. Install `expo-constants` by running this on your project directory:

```
expo install expo-constants
```

2. import Constants where needed as follows

```
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
```

3. Retrieve statusBarHeight like this:

```
const barHeight = Constants.statusBarHeight;
```

More on the new documentations for Expo SDK 34 can be found [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v34.0.0/sdk/constants/).

Hope this Helps!